# Parsear csv con comillas problematicas

Tags: java, regex, csv

tengo que leer el siguiente csv:

```
,codigo,nom,cognom
,111,michael,salinas
,222,"luis","doh, \”jik"
,333,ram,"Lak""\""""\""""\"" , ""\""“one"
```

Se supone que son 4 columnas, pero tengo problemas con la última fila, para leer el csv estoy usando un matcher:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]+?)\"|(?<=,|^)([^,]*)(?=,|$)").matcher(line);
```

Pero no consigo que la última línea la separe bien, me aparece así:

- 333
- ram
- "Lak"
- "\"
- "\"
- "\"
- " , "
- "\"
- "“one"

Alguna idea de como arreglar ésto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viendo la sintaxis que estás utilizando en tu CSV, se permiten comillas embebidas escapadas como dobles (`""`), y una barra (`\`) no se toma como caracter especial.

Para que coincida con un texto entre comillas, permitiendo `""` dentro de éstas, se pueden buscar todos los caracteres que no sean `"`, seguidos opcionalmente por cualquier cantidad de `""` y más caracteres. Es decir:

```
"[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*"
```

- Si bien hay patrones más acotados para esto mismo, esta es la forma más eficiente de realizarlo, empleando una técnica llamada *[unrolling the loop](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop)*.

El regex completo, para elementos con o sin comillas, sería:

```
,("[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*"|[^,]+)
```

---

#### Código

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

```java
final String[] csv =  new String[] {      // Líneas de la pregunta
    ",codigo,nom,cognom",
    ",111,michael,salinas",
    ",222,\"luis\",\"doh, \\”jik\"",
    ",333,ram,\"Lak\"\"\\\"\"\"\"\\\"\"\"\"\\\"\" , \"\"\\\"\"“one\""
};

final String regex = ",(\"[^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*\"|[^,]+)";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

for (String line : csv) {  // loop a cada línea
    System.out.println("Línea: " + line);
    
    final Matcher m = pattern.matcher(line);
    
    while (m.find()) {  // loop a cada coincidencia (cada elemento sin la coma)
        // Imprimimos el grupo 1 (lo que coincidió entre paréntesis)
        System.out.println("  Elemento: " + m.group(1));
    }
}
```

#### Salida

```
Línea: ,codigo,nom,cognom
  Elemento: codigo
  Elemento: nom
  Elemento: cognom
Línea: ,111,michael,salinas
  Elemento: 111
  Elemento: michael
  Elemento: salinas
Línea: ,222,"luis","doh, \”jik"
  Elemento: 222
  Elemento: "luis"
  Elemento: "doh, \”jik"
Línea: ,333,ram,"Lak""\""""\""""\"" , ""\""“one"
  Elemento: 333
  Elemento: ram
  Elemento: "Lak""\""""\""""\"" , ""\""“one"
```

<kbd>[Demo en ideone](http://ideone.com/jA7S42)</kbd>